# How do I get private mentions in tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

I am going to make a simple die bot using twiffy and apiv2.
When my dice bot mentions Y/N, it answers either Yes or No with a mention.
It works well with public accounts, but it does not load mentions from private accounts.
What should I do?

```
import tweepy
import random
import time


def main():

    consumer_key = ""
    consumer_secret = ""
    access_token = ""
    access_token_secret = ""
    bearer_token = ""

    client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key=consumer_key, consumer_secret=consumer_secret, access_token=access_token, access_token_secret=access_token_secret, bearer_token=bearer_token)

    id = ''

    last_mention = 0

    yesno = ['Y', 'N']

    while True:
        mentions = client.get_users_mentions(id=id, since_id = last_mention).data
        print(mentions)
        if mentions:
            for mention in mentions:
                tweet_id = mention.id
                tweet_txt = mention.text
                answer = 0
                answer_txt = ''


                if 'Y/N' in tweet_txt:
                    text = yesno[random.randrange(0, 2)]
                    client.create_tweet(text=text, in_reply_to_tweet_id=tweet_id)
                    last_mention = tweet_id
                    continue
                time.sleep(5)
        else:
            time.sleep(5)
            pass



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I read the user field of the tweepy document, but there was no extension using 'protected' field.